# How do I restrict a resource handle I generate to one client from a linux shared library

Tags: c++, linux, security, shared-libraries, handle

I have a shared library that hands out an integer handle to a client after a successful connection request. Something like:

```
int ConnectionRequest(const std::string& authorization_token);
```

Subsequent actions then need to use that handle to access further operations:

```
result DoOperation(int handle, const std::string& payload);
```

It occurred to me that a second client could hijack the connection simply by presenting a plausible handle value to the interface. How do I uniquely link the handle to the client that made the original request? Is there a way to get the process ID from the client and check against it?

Internally I use a std::map to link the handle to a shared_ptr object. All this is in user space.

Coding on linux in C++.

Comment: To what degrees are you required to lock down this possibility? All of the simple solutions have simple attacks that can get around the countermeasure. Are you trying to prevent accidents or malice?

Comment: @user4581301 Malice. It is a platform where 3rd party applications may run, and there should be at least a baseline defense. At the moment my best idea I am testing is to record process and thread ID on connect and verify future interactions with this.

Comment: Could your integer 'handle' be a hash value - not perhaps super secure but it would make it harder for a malicious caller to guess?

Comment: Encrypt it. If you're worried about attackers, you might as well go all in. Anything you send can be recorded and used against you, be it by extracting the the ID info and crafting new messages or simply playing the updating a few parameters and playing the message back. At the most simple (and assuming the attacker doesn't know the keys) an attacker's message will be garbage and can be easily identified and discarded. If the attacker does know your keys, you're probably already <expletive deleted>ed. Sidenote: Don't roll your own crypto. It never works.

Comment: @JimmyNJ Yes - I considered that and may do, but I'd much prefer something that works even if the handle is known or easily guessed.

Comment: Could you use a combination of your authorization id /and/  the handle value you intend to return? So then Have the client side handle type be a struct with the hashed combination and a repeat of the int handle. You can then verify the caller is the owner of the handle.

Answer (score 1):

Both Linux and Windows have already solved this problem - you can look to their implementations for a working method.

In short, use multiple tables.

When referencing handles given out by the kernel, the system needs to ensure that a rogue process can't just steal your file handle and access your data. To do so, the system creates a per-process handle table that contains only the handles relevant to your process. If a rogue process steals one of your handles and tries to use it, they won't be able to access your data - the OS will index their handle table, and find either nothing, or one of their resources.

You can duplicate this behavior by looking up a handle table via process ID first, then look up the structure with the handle provided. If the process ID doesn't exist in the handle table map, return an error. Otherwise, run the function on the structure referenced by the handle if it exists.

Comment: I am in user space, and my resources are not automatically restricted. I cannot therefore rely on per-process tables. My current effort maintains a static std::map managed by a singleton. On connection I store pid and tid, then for each action on the handle I verify that pid and tid still match. This _may_ be how the OS is doing it - I don't know.

Comment: The OS uses the calling process structure and per process tables. You can do the same thing provided you can retrieve the process ID of the requesting client from the OS. No need for kernel resources - you're simply leveraging the algorithmic design used by this small section of the kernel.